# Android Dev: How to get a GeoPoint by LONG PRESS on MapView?

Tags: android, android-mapview, long-press

I want to get a specific GeoPoint to do something by LONG PRESS (NOT CLICK BUT LONG PRESS) a point on a MapView.

I found online only this way to do this:
http://www.kind-kristiansen.no/2010/handling-longpresslongclick-in-mapactivity/

but this way considers the LONG PRESS in every part of the screen not only in MapView and the geopoint is not accurate.

Can you give me an working example to do this?

Thank you very very much!

Comment: Solved: http://www.kind-kristiansen.no/2011/android-handling-longpresslongclick-on-map-revisited/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer or not but I found the updated tutorial by the same author [here](http://www.kind-kristiansen.no/2011/android-handling-longpresslongclick-on-map-revisited/) handier.